# Enable Opensearch in Geonetwork (version > 3.2)

Tags: opensearch, geonetwork, opensearchdescription

I want to be able to search against a Geonetwork catalog by using the Opensearch protocol.

I already read that Opensearch should be enabled by a file descriptor that is put on this path of the GN instance:
http:///geonetwork/srv/eng/portal.opensearch

An example of this document is [here](http://www.fao.org/geonetwork/srv/en/portal.opensearch). It contains search templates.

- How can i enable Opensearch?
- How can i customize it?
- I would also like to know if there's any useful documentation on this matter.

Comment: Thats not how questions are asked on Stack Overflow. Please have a look at [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve].

Comment: @L.Guthardt Yeah, i was expecting that since i post from a new account. I tried to ask a question as simple and generic as possible because unfortunately i cannot find anything on this subject and I think that a more specific and technical question would not be useful. You could illuminate me if you want, and if you have something on the subject i would be thankful.